# Plotting 3D Vector Field in one plane

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, vector

I want to plot a vector field `F={Fx, Fy, Fz}`. However, I only want to plot it in one plane (say, z=0).

When I use `VectorPlot3D[{Fx, Fy, Fz}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, x}]`, and `x=0`, I get

> VectorPlot3D::plld: "Endpoints for z in {z,0,0} must have distinct machine-precision numerical values."

and when `x=0.1`, it gives me several layers of vectors, which I do not want.

So the question is: **How can I plot a 3D-Vector-Field only in a 2-dimensional plane?**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Now you can either use `ViewPoint`

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 200}]
```

[image]

or define a very small z-range

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0.001, 0.001}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{
  VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, ##},
     VectorColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors",
     PlotTheme -> "Marketing",
     ImageSize -> 300] & @@@
   {{-0.2, -0.199}, {-0.001, 0.001}, {0.199, 0.2}}
  }]
```

[image]

If you dare and have **V10** you could also use `ClipPlanes`:

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D",
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing",
 ImageSize -> 600,
 ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, -10, -5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: oh very nice, thank you. I tried to restrict the z-region, but i didnt do it symmetric and small enough. This works very nicely for me - i see the 3-dimensional vectors of one plane. thanks!